# UltraESB-X Server

Tags: ultraesb, adroitlogic

I created my first Integration flow project in Ultrastudio. I proceeded step by step, according to the official documentation, as shown [here](https://developer.adroitlogic.com/ultrastudio/docs/17.07/creating_running_flow.html). I have successfully build the project and then I configured UltraESB-X Server in IntelliJ IDEA. Then I received Response in HTTP/S Client tool but when I want to show Message content or Highlight Message Execution Path I receivee error massage: Failed to obtain execution path. Make sure UltraESB-X server is running. But IntelliJ IDEA studio received this:

```
INFO XContainer AdroitLogic UltraStudio UltraESB-X server started successfully in 3 seconds and 885 milliseconds
```

Can anyone help me with that?

OS: Windows 10,
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA ultimate v. 2020.1

Edit:

I noticed that after starting the IDE there is a plugin exception:

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: While loading class org.adroitlogic.ustudio.core.ui.UltraProjectViewProvider: Cannot inherit from final class [Plugin: org.adroitlogic.UltraStudio]
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:262)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:205)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:113)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.getImplementationClass(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:80)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionComponentAdapter.createInstance(ExtensionComponentAdapter.java:39)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.createInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.java:68)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapter(ExtensionPointImpl.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapters(ExtensionPointImpl.java:401)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensionList(ExtensionPointImpl.java:232)
at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ProjectExtensionPointName.getExtensions(ProjectExtensionPointName.java:28)
at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.ProjectAbstractTreeStructureBase.getProviders(ProjectAbstractTreeStructureBase.java:23)
at com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeStructureBase.getChildElements(AbstractTreeStructureBase.java:40)
at com.intellij.ui.tree.StructureTreeModel.getValidChildren(StructureTreeModel.java:384)
at com.intellij.ui.tree.StructureTreeModel.validateChildren(StructureTreeModel.java:298)
at com.intellij.ui.tree.StructureTreeModel.getNode(StructureTreeModel.java:292)
at com.intellij.ui.tree.StructureTreeModel.getChildren(StructureTreeModel.java:312)
at com.intellij.ui.tree.AsyncTreeModel$CmdGetChildren.getNode(AsyncTreeModel.java:573)
at com.intellij.ui.tree.AsyncTreeModel$ObsolescentCommand.get(AsyncTreeModel.java:468)
at com.intellij.ui.tree.AsyncTreeModel$ObsolescentCommand.get(AsyncTreeModel.java:434)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.Invoker$Task.run(Invoker.java:323)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1106)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.lambda$runInReadActionWithWriteActionPriority$0(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:75)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.lambda$runWithWriteActionPriority$1(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:129)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:166)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:153)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runWithWriteActionPriority(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:118)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runInReadActionWithWriteActionPriority(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:75)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.Invoker.invokeSafely(Invoker.java:206)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.Invoker.lambda$offerSafely$0(Invoker.java:184)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.Invoker$Background.lambda$offer$0(Invoker.java:524)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:222)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:201)
at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:210)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:190)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you're running plugin v 17.07.4 - do you have any other Java processes running at the time of the failure (except IDEA)?

Comment: @JanakaBandara Thank you for you answer. Yes, I am using UltraStudio Plugin (17.07.4 (Windows)) and there is no other Java process running at the time of the failure. I noticed that after starting the IDE there is a plugin exception, which is mentioned in the first post. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! We'll check into the plugin exception - possibly an incompatibility with 2020.1. Meanwhile, can you try these steps, in order: (1) Change the IDE boot JDK to the natively installed JDK, [as mentioned here](https://developer.adroitlogic.com/ultrastudio/docs/17.07/faq.html#q-message-execution-paths-are-not-getting-highlighted), and retry to see if the highlighting works then; (2) Search for the phrase "Failed to obtain the local" in the IDEA logfile (*Help -> Show Log in Explorer*) and tally the log line timestamp with the time of your issue occurrence, if you find one

Comment: @JanakaBandara Thank you for your help. I reinstall IntelliJ IDEA and set JDK 1.8.x (x64) version in IDE. I originally used the version JDK 1.8.x x86  - this caused: 

UltraStudio -> Failed to obtain the local JMX Service URL for the config file: C:/Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/sample; Unable to attach to 32-bit process running under WOW64  

Now everything works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Vit! We hadn't encountered this specific issue (`Unable to attach to 32-bit process running under WOW64`) before; we'll add it to our troubleshooting documentation. Also, please consider adding it as the answer to this question itself, so that others can use it as a reference in future!